# El entrecomillado de la descripción de un producto me devuelve error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Cuando trato de integrar a mi base de datos el siguiente producto: *Headset Razer ManO'War Wireless 7.1* me marca el siguiente error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WAR WIRELESS 7.1'

En español:

> Error la sintaxis de *SQL*. Compruebe el manual que corresponde a su versión del servidor *MySQL* para la sintaxis correcta para usar *War Wireless 7.1*.

Investigando un poco encontré estas líneas de código que según creo, tienen relación con mi problema:

```
if( is_null($producto_descripcion) ) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO #__virtuemart_products_{$prefix_tabla}(
                virtuemart_product_id,
                product_name,
                slug
              ) VALUES (
                '$product_id',
                '$value->descripcion',
                '$value->skuFabricante-{$product_id}'
            )";
        } else {
            if($only_stock == "0") {
                $query = "UPDATE  #__virtuemart_products_{$prefix_tabla} SET
                  product_name ='$value->descripcion'
                WHERE virtuemart_product_id = '$product_id'";
```

el detalle esta en: product_name y su '$value->descripcion' pero aun no se que hacer,algo que si tengo muy claro es que debe reescribirse todo el codigo para adecuarse a los nuevos estandares,es correcto?

Comment: Como te dijeron abajo, son problemas de escapado. Al añadir una cadena con comillas simples  estás terminando la cadena cuando no debería y el texto sobrante te está dando un error.

Comment: Hola @gmo, ¿solucionaste el problema? Gracias.

Comment: no exactamente @OscarGarcia,veras yo tengo conocimientos muy basicos de esto asi que voy muy lento pero al parecer tendre que buscar quien me corrija el codigo. completo de momento me interesaba corregir eso "rapido" por que esta en producicion no en pruebas y esta deteniendo las actualizaciones

Comment: ¿"No exactamente" qué significa? ¿Este problema específico se solucionó y tienes otros? ¿Este problema sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: @OscarGarcia no se mucho de codigo y la persona que veia esto ya no trabaja aqui,asi que bueno tengo que apañarmelas solo, de momento el error se ha solucionado agregando en;. product_name y su '$value->descripcion' ,lo siguiente: '".$db->escape($value->descripcion)."', ahora tengo un error que dice:
Duplicate entry '100' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO#__virtuemart_products_{$prefix_tabla}

Comment: Has cambiado radicalmente el código porque antes no usabas OOP, pero en esencia has hecho algo similar, escapar las comillas. Ese error es habitual, simplemente estás insertando un nuevo registro que no cumple la restricción de clave primaria. Si lo que quieres es insertar un registro que puede existir y, si eso ocurre, lo actualice, entonces debes usar [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html). La sintaxis es la de un INSERT, pero en caso de repetir clave primaria hace un UPDATE en vez de INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que sufres está relacionado con un [mal escapado de la consulta SQL](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__virtuemart_products_{$prefix_tabla} WHERE slug = '" .
  mysql_real_escape_string($value->skuFabricante . "-" . $product_id) .
  "' and virtuemart_product_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($product_id) . "'";
```

Debes hacer uso de [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) para poder insertar cadenas de caracteres dentro de consultas SQL para evitar que una cadena `Esta'prueba` convierta un `campo='Esta'Prueba` en una cadena `campo='Esta'` y un error de sintaxis por la palabra suelta `Prueba`.

OJO: Ten en cuenta que si `$prefix_tabla` no está bajo tu control (es un campo enviado desde un formulario, por ejemplo) podría darte problemas en un futuro si no realizas una comprobación exhaustiva de su contenido.

PD: Usa las consultas preparadas de [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) o [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli), evita las funciones `mysql_*`. Están obsoletas y han sido eliminadas en PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el error tiene que ver con las comillas, para saber dar una mejor respuesta tendría que conocer un poco mas de tu código, pero centrándome en las comillas te diré que revises esto.

Cambia lo siguiente que esta copiado de la primer linea de tu código

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__virtuemart_products_{$prefix_tabla} WHERE slug = '$value->skuFabricante-{$product_id}' and virtuemart_product_id = '$product_id'";
```

de la siguiente forma:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__virtuemart_products_{".$prefix_tabla."} WHERE slug = '".$value->skuFabricante-{$product_id}."' and virtuemart_product_id = '".$product_id."'";
```

y revisa que todas las variables estén así.

Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

EDITADO

También te sugiero que no utilices comillas ' en los strings,cámbialos por un - sino tendrás muchos problemas ya que la usar una comillas dentro del nombre te dara erro al no ser cerrada apropiadamente. por ej: $val = "a'b" dentro del query se interpretaría como error. revisa sql injection para mas información. ej:

```
query = " select * from table where string = 'a'b'"
```

el interprete te diria que hay un error de sintax cerca de 'b'.

:.
EDITADO

Lo mejor es utilizar [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), si no estas usandodo PDO para conectarte a la base de datos aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo
[stackoverflow.com - keywords - PDO CLASS CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes)

```
 */
Config::write('db.host', 'localhost');
Config::write('db.port', '3306');
Config::write('db.basename', 'puravida');
Config::write('db.user', 'root');
Config::write('db.password', '');

class Config {

    static $confArray; 

    public static function read($name) {
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }

    public static function write($name, $value) {
        self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
    }
}

class Core {
    public $dbh; // manejador de conexion de la base de datos.
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()  {

        $conexion = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') . ';dbname=' . Config::read('db.basename') .';charset=utf8'. ';port=' . Config::read('db.port') .';connect_timeout=15';
        $user = Config::read('db.user');
        $password = Config::read('db.password');
        $this->dbh = new PDO($conexion, $user, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);// desactivar emulación de querys peparadors
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);// lanzar excepciones.
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

?>
 y la función que hace la consulta a la base de datos es la siguiente.

```
<?php
function CargarLinksGeneral($id)
{
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dbcore/dbcore.php';
    $qury='select accesos.acceso, accesos.url, accesos.descripcion FROM accesos INNER JOIN nivelesacceso ON nivelesacceso.idacceso = accesos.idacceso INNER JOIN niveles ON nivelesacceso.idnivel = niveles.idnivel INNER JOIN rolesnivel ON niveles.idnivel = rolesnivel.idnivel WHERE rolesnivel.idrol ='.$id;
    try {
        $bd=Core::getInstance();
        $qbdobj=$bd->dbh->prepare($qury); /**ESTA LINEA ES PDO::prepare*/
        if ($qbdobj->execute()) {
            $qbdobj->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $qbdobj->fetchall();
        }
        else
            {
                return NULL;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }   
}
```

?>
Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos! por si no quedo claro el problema es ocasionado por la comilla en ManO'War ya sea que este encapsulada en una variable ($val) al ejecutar el query digamos ("... WHERE id ='".$val."'") se interpretara como "... EHRE id = ManO'War" lo cual abre una comilla que no se interpreta como un string. teóricamente (según lo que yo entiendo) cuando uses PDO::prepare esa comilla sera tomada como un string.

**EDITADO**

como no estaba seguro de mis afirmaciones investigue un poco y encontré lo siguiente [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) tal vez sea de utilidad.

Comment: el problema es que yo no se mucho sobre esto asi que voy muy lento con la localizacion del error,ya aisle la parte donde se genera el problema (segun yo)el detalle esta en: product_name y su '$value->descripcion' pero aun no se que hacer debo declararla como variable?